# Reading an unknown number of lines in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the code below, but it specifies the number of lines in the file. I'm wondering how I can change it so that it will read an unknown number of lines?

```
n = int(input("instance: "))
tp, tn, fp, fn = 0
for i in range(n):
    real, predicted = map(int, input().split(' '))
    for num in i:
        if real == 1 and predicted == 1:
            tp += 1
        elif real == 0 and predicted == 0:
            tn += 1
        elif real == 1 and predicted == 0:
            fn += 1
        else:
            fp += 1

pr = tp / (tp + fp)
rc = tp / (tp + fn)
f1 = 2 * ((pr * rc) / (pr + rc))
print("f1= ", f1)
```

My code reads these lines and compares numbers on each line with each other, but not with numbers on the other lines.

The input looks like this:

```
1 1
0 0
0 1
0 1
1 0
0 1
0 0
1 1
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
1 1
```

Comment: How is the program supposed to know it has reached the end of the list?

Comment: I doubt this runs, since `for num in i` would raise a `TypeError: int is not iterable`

Comment: @ScottHunter Well, actually that's my question, I know how to write it if the number of lines are given, otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: what exactly id the input? is it a file?

Comment: I didn't ask how to *code* it; I asked what you expect to use to indicate that the list is done.

Answer (score 2):

Keep reading until `EOFError` is thrown:

```
tp, tn, fp, fn = 0
i = 0
try:
    while True:
        real, predicted = map(int, input().split(' '))
        for num in i:
            if real == 1 and predicted == 1:
                tp += 1
            elif real == 0 and predicted == 0:
                tn += 1
            elif real == 1 and predicted == 0:
                fn += 1
            else:
                fp += 1
        i += 1
except EOFError:
    pass
pr = tp / (tp + fp)
rc = tp / (tp + fn)
f1 = 2 * ((pr * rc) / (pr + rc))
print("f1= ", f1)
```

Your code has errors too:

- multiple variables can't be assigned to the same value using unpacking.
- `range` needs to be used if you want to count up to a number.

This should fix them:

```
tp = tn = fp = fn = 0
i = 0
try:
    while True:
        real, predicted = map(int, input().split(' '))
        for num in range(i):
            if real == 1 and predicted == 1:
                tp += 1
            elif real == 0 and predicted == 0:
                tn += 1
            elif real == 1 and predicted == 0:
                fn += 1
            else:
                fp += 1
        i += 1
except EOFError:
    pass
pr = tp / (tp + fp)
rc = tp / (tp + fn)
f1 = 2 * ((pr * rc) / (pr + rc))
print("f1= ", f1)
```

Comment: Do you know how to store each line in a list and then do the comparison? Because `for num in i:` wont work, is not iterable.

Comment: @Nebula Are you trying to do `for num in range(i):`?

Comment: btw you can assign multiple variables to the same value but you have to do it like this: `tp = tn = fp = fn = 0`

Comment: @Boendal Thanks. That's the better way to do it.